# How to fix decoding transaction data giving wrong output in ethers-rs?

Tags: rust, data

I am trying to decode the hex data of a transaction. For testing purposes I am using the transaction that can be found here https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xad76a2d244b66d44415135dedd03a127bbfdf36bf0eee68a7c857f8dff7be7fa

It clearly states that the function is `Function: addToCurrentNumber(uint256 _toAdd)` hence the input type is `uint256` and the original hex value is `0xa934861a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005`

The decoded value can also be seen as 5.

Now in my code I have the following

```
use ethers::abi::decode;
use ethers::abi::ParamType;
use ethers::core::utils::hex::decode as hex_decode;
fn main() {
    let vec1 = hex_decode("a934861a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005").unwrap();
    let data: &[u8] = vec1.as_slice();
    let result = decode(
        vec![ParamType::Uint(256)].as_slice(),
        data
    ).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

But when I run this, the output is `[Uint(76533672992909578901694265460808195815504318440232336607848770502130973802496)]` which is not what I was expecting. I was expecting 5.

Am I doing something wrong? Or this is working as expected and I am missing the API?

Comment: You might want to use `abigen` instead of manually decoding the output. https://docs.rs/ethers-contract/0.1.3/ethers_contract/struct.Abigen.html

Comment: Are you removing the function selector from the bytes string?

Answer (score 0):

**Markus Schick** - was absolutely right: *а function selector is the first 4 bytes of the call data for a function call that specifies the function to be called*
In your case selector is - `0xa934861a` (`addToCurrentNumber`) the rest is a number: `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005`